# How to check google analytics api parameters from google analytics interface

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using `google analytics api` to get data. I am getting data but I want to verify two parameters those are always 0 in a particular date range. I am getting `['ga:transactions']` and `['ga:goalCompletionsAll']` . These two parameters are always zero in google analytics api response.

So I just want to know is there any way I can check these two parameters from google analytics web interface against some particular date range?

Answer (score 2):

You could test it using a Custom report on the website:

[image]

[Link](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=vo359BceTOaWjHkSwNbzIA) to the custom report above, just import it it will show with your data.

The report is just [Goal Completions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions&jump=ga_goalcompletionsall) and [transactions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_transactions) by [Date](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date)

Comment: @DalmTo it is just showing two dates 7th feb and 8th feb. But my date range for report is selcted from 6th feb to 8th march. So this report only shows the dates where there is some data?

Comment: Correct if there is no data it wont return anything